# firebase hosting iframe error with X-Frame-Options

Tags: firebase, routes, cors, firebase-hosting

I need to use couple of iframe for a page hosted with firebase, but its giving me X-Frame-Options error, one of the iframe is for gallery hosted on picasa, and anohter ifrmae for contact form(because i couldnt sent email via firebase :()

here is error

```
Refused to display 'https://get.google.com/albumarchive/pwa/11111/album/1111?source=pwa#slideshow/1111' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://demodomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

i did this with firebase.json but didnt worked

```
 "headers": [
     {
       "source": "**/*",
       "headers": [
         {"key": "X-Content-Type-Options", "value": "nosniff"},
         {"key": "X-Frame-Options", "value": "ALLOW"},
         {"key": "X-UA-Compatible", "value": "ie=edge"},
         {"key": "X-XSS-Protection", "value": "1; mode=block"}
       ]
     }
]
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

you have the right idea you're just setting the wrong value. ALLOW is not an acceptable value for the X-Frame-Options header. You can set the ALLOW-FROM value and then specify which uri you want to allow to be able to embed. Check out some more documentation below.

FIX:

```
 "headers": [{
   "source": "**/*",
   "headers": [
     {"key": "X-Content-Type-Options", "value": "nosniff"},
     {"key": "X-Frame-Options", "value": "ALLOW-FROM https://get.google.com"},
     {"key": "X-UA-Compatible", "value": "ie=edge"},
     {"key": "X-XSS-Protection", "value": "1; mode=block"}
   ]
 }]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: would you know if things have changed since your original post? i've implemented the above headers but i'm still able to firame my page from another site. I'm testing it via stackblitz.com

Comment: `ALLOW-FROM` [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#directives) and should not be used.